# 'DocX' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I want to inherit from `DocX`, to integrate InterOp printing of Word documents:

```
public class WordDoc : DocX {
    static private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp;

    static WordDoc() {
    }
}
```

but when I try that, I get this error:

> 'DocX' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

From metadata I can see that no constructors are defined at all, so I reckon the empty constructor should be generated. I also do not provide a constructor for my base class.

I do have the static constructor, but when I remove it, I still get the same error.

Comment: "From metadata I can see that no constructors are defined at all, so I reckon the empty constructor should be generated." No, if any default constructor would be generated *by the compiler* so would be in the metadata.

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation of `DocX`?

Comment: @JonSkeet https://docx.codeplex.com/

Comment: Assuming it's [this](https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX/blob/master/DocX/DocX.cs) it has an internal constructor, which you should be able to see in the metadata..

Comment: @JonSkeet I used the "Go To Definition [F12]" option in Visual Studio 2015, but I cannot see that constructor there. Is there a way to get more info?

Comment: Yes, you can use ILdasm, Reflector etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DocX/DocX.cs), you will see that a constructor is indeed declared:

```
internal DocX(DocX document, XElement xml)
        : base(document, xml)
{
}
```

That said, considering that it is marked `internal`, it would seem that this class is **NOT** intended to be the public API and as such, you should neither attempt to instantiate it directly or inherit from it.

Rather, all of the [examples](https://docx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Examples/Program.cs) seem to be relying on the static `Create` method in that class:

```
public static DocX Create(string filename, 
    DocumentTypes documentType = DocumentTypes.Document)
{
    // Store this document in memory
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    // Create the docx package
    //WordprocessingDocument wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(ms, 
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    PostCreation(package, documentType);
    DocX document = DocX.Load(ms);
    document.filename = filename;
    return document;
}
```

Comment: @BartFriederichs whoops, I absolutely did, thank you :).  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Class you are trying to inherit from has one **internal** constructor:

```
internal DocX(DocX document, XElement xml)
  : base(document, xml)
{
}
```

So you cannot inherit from this class. If you omit default constructor, compiler will generate this:

```
public WordDoc() : base() {

}
```

But `base()` constructor is not accessible (internal). If you create default constructor:

```
public WordDoc() {

}
```

Compiler will still add call to `base()`, because you cannot inherit from class and somehow omit calling any of this base class constructors.

So instead of inheritance - use other ways, like extension methods, proxy class and so on, depending on concrete problem you are solving.